# API send email and Password using CURL

Tags: php, json, wordpress, email, curl

I have written some code into a plugin for Wordpress that when the User hits the submit button their information is stored in the WP database and is also sent to a third party website with their email and password using JSON protocalls.

this is the code I use (the "$bemail" and $password are referring to earlier parts of the code in the same file):

```
$url = "https://api.example.com/v1/logins";
$data = array(
    'email'     => $_POST['$bemail'],
    'password'  => $_POST['$password'],
    );
$content = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($url);
$apikey = "xxxx";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'example.com-Api-Key: ' . $apikey,
    'Accept: application/json',
    ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

I get an error with a response from the 3rd party website with something like:

"error: email and password cannot be blank"

which tells me that the email and password is not being sent.

what am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you forwarding the user's email and password to a 3rd party???

Comment: the users pay to use my WP website, the website uses videos for education, however, in order to view the videos the users need to input their email and password into the video itself, they used when signing up to allow access and view the video. For now I have to upload their email manually and give them a password I made in order for them to be able to view a video.

Comment: Ok. I've written a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To tell the receiving server to expect JSON, use the `Content-Type` header instead of `Accept`:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'example.com-Api-Key: ' . $apikey,
    // remove this line -> 'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
```

Comment: thank you for your response, after applying the solution, the problem remains the same, the exact response is: Error: call to URL https://api.example.com/v1/logins failed with status 400, response {"error":{"errors":{"email":["is invalid","can't be blank"],"password_confirmation":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}}, curl_error , curl_errno 0 ------------- do you think the problem is that my code isnt actually pulling the user form information?

Comment: I don't know. It could be that, or you're not building the post fields as the API expects.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest is to just use our PHP API client which you can find here: https://github.com/sproutvideo/sproutvideo-php

The documentation for creating a login is here: https://github.com/sproutvideo/sproutvideo-php#create_login

You can also see what is being received on the server side by logging into your account and going to http://sproutvideo.com/api_history

If you have any further questions about getting set up with the API, please reach out to our customer support directly!